# How to change the form action attribute for a search bar

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to Javascript and web development in general, so any help is appreciated! I have a form which sets up a simple search bar. I want the form to go the a url dependent on what the user types into the search bar. I've looked up other answers, and none of them seem to work for me. Here is the relevant code:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
    function formSubmit(element){
        var url = $("#search_form").attr("action");
        var newParam = element.value;
        url += "/" + newParam;
        $("#search_form").attr("action", url);
        $("#search_form")[0].submit();
    }
</script>

<form action='./search' method="post" id="search_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="search_item">Search: </label>
    <input id="search_item" type="text" name="search_item" value="{{ search_item }}" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" onsubmit="formSubmit(search_item)">
```

Basically, when the user types in an input, I want the form to go to '/search/user_input_here'. I can't seem to get it working though.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use jQuery so this is quite easy

```
 $("#search_form").submit(function(){
     $(this).attr('action', $(this).attr('action') + '/' + $('#search_item').val());
     return true;
 });
```

Comment: Sorry for being so naive, but were exactly should I be putting this code? I tried both putting it before and inside of my form and it doesn't work for me. Thanks!

Comment: submit btn doesn't need to call your js function, onsubmit="formSubmit(search_item)", remove it and of course put my code inside the script tags that it's loaded when page loads, then when you press the submit btn my code should be executed. try to add an alert/console.log for debugging